# How show checkbox value before submit OR there itself when ticked?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have the following codes:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="apple" id="apple" /><label   for="apple">Apple</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="pinapple" id="pinapple" /><label for="pinapple">Pinapple</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="grapefruit" id="grapefruit" /><label for="grapefruit">Grapefruit</label><br />
<input type="submit" name="go" />
</form>
<?php 
$fruitList = implode(', ', $_POST['fruit']);
echo $fruitList;
?>
```

It will show the checked items after submit. Is this possible show the ticked items values inside a input box before submitting.

Comment: The items are right next to the checkboxes. What's the issue with them not showing? They're right there!

Comment: Is this possible to show inside a input box, what all checked before submit?

Comment: Do you know any javascript?

Comment: You will need to use JavaScript to update the input box's text value on load and when the check state is changed on any of the checkboxes.

Comment: Your post is do damn confusing.

Answer (score 1):

The only way i can think of is to attach an event to the checkboxes and display the clicked ones on another area. Assuming you are using `JQuery`, the code should be something like this:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() { // Listen to change on your checkbox
  var checked = '';
  $.each($('input[type=checkbox]:checked'), function(k, v) { // Iterate through the checked ones
     checked = checked + v + ' / '; // Append the value to a string
  }
  $('#display_results').html(v); // Replace the content of a div, span, whatever
});
```

Load this code on `document.ready` and try to tweak it to suit your needs.
Of course the code needs some change, but the basic idea is this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it certainly is but it will take some javascript code.

Here is an example based on the code snippet you pasted:

http://jsfiddle.net/EmNSe/

```
<form method="post" name="myForm">
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="apple" id="apple" onclick="selectionListener();" />
    <label for="apple">Apple</label>
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="pinapple" id="pinapple" onclick="selectionListener();" />
    <label for="pinapple">Pinapple</label>
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="grapefruit" id="grapefruit" onclick="selectionListener();" />
    <label for="grapefruit">Grapefruit</label>
    <br />
    <br />
    <label for="SelectionMade">Selection Made:</label>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name-"SelectionMade" id="SelectionMade">
    </textarea>
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="go" />
</form>
```

and the javascript:

```
function selectionListener() {

    checkedStr = '';

    if (document.getElementById('grapefruit').checked) {
        checkedStr = checkedStr + "grapefruit is checked!\n";
    }

    if (document.getElementById('pinapple').checked) {
        checkedStr = checkedStr + "pinapple is checked!\n";
    }
    if (document.getElementById('apple').checked) {
        checkedStr = checkedStr + "apple is checked!\n";
    }

    document.getElementById('SelectionMade').value = checkedStr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Full example

If you confirm it sends everything else it stops.

1. works with unlimited checkboxes.
2. one eventListener.
3. compatibility: needs `e.preventDefault()`(first example only) and `querySelectorAll()`
4. in querySelectorAll() you can also add the name of the checkbox set.
5. Pure javascript.

---

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>checkbox</title>
<style>
</style>
<script>
(function(W){
 var D;
 function init(){
  D=W.document;
  D.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].addEventListener('submit',h,false);
 }
 function h(e){
  var s=this.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked'),l=s.length,a=[];
  while(l--){a[l]=s[l].value;}
  confirm(a.join(', '))?null:e.preventDefault();
 }
 W.addEventListener('load',init,false)  
})(window)
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="apple" id="apple" /><label   for="apple">Apple</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="pinapple" id="pinapple" /><label for="pinapple">Pinapple</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="grapefruit" id="grapefruit" /><label for="grapefruit">Grapefruit</label><br />
<input type="submit" name="go" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want the results in a input filed on change:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>checkbox</title>
<style>
</style>
<script>
(function(W){
 var D;
 function init(){
  D=W.document;
  D.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].addEventListener('change',h2,false);
 }
 function h2(e){
  var s=this.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked'),l=s.length,a=[];
  while(l--){a[l]=s[l].value;}
  D.getElementById('fruits').value=a.join(', ');
 }
 W.addEventListener('load',init,false)  
})(window)
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="apple" id="apple" /><label   for="apple">Apple</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="pinapple" id="pinapple" /><label for="pinapple">Pinapple</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="grapefruit" id="grapefruit" /><label for="grapefruit">Grapefruit</label><br />
<input type="submit" name="go" />
</form>
<input id="fruits">
</body>
</html>
```